# Where can I find a list of string use to access aggregate data?

Tags: ember.js

When we declare a computed property OR an observer we do the following,

```
  fullName: Ember.computed('firstName', 'lastName', function() {
    return `${this.get('firstName')} ${this.get('lastName')}`;
  })
```

We first declare a string which stands for the value we need to the observer; however, these are the simplest way to observe some value.

There are cases we need to observe array's length or the content inside it.

I know we can use `arrayName.[]` to observer the length of the array but I would like to know where can I find a detailed reference on how to use these string thing to get what I want.

Currently, everything still feels magical to me, for example, I do not really understand what `arrayName.@each` do.

Comment: of course in ember guides [computed-properties-and-aggregate-data](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/). Read it and try it if you find problem then ask question with code here

Comment: Thanks, I did see that section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read more about computed property and how to use the string to represent aggregate data at,

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/

The common ones are

`arrayName.@each.propertyName`, to observe the property for each element inside array

However, this only work **one level** deep and you cannot use nested form.

`arrayName.[]`, to observe the length of array.